# Struggling with nested lists in c#

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm working in a lot of unknown territory for me, as I'm trying to properly follow MVVM in this project, as well as proper structuring.  I have created the following class based on how a json document will be laid out in the future:

```
    public class SkinList
    {
        public class Coord
        {
            public string x { get; set; }
            public string y { get; set; }
        }

        public class Location
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Coord> Coords { get; set; }
            public string CodeNumber { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

        public class Skin
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Skin> Skins { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The current page creates a new Skin (skin) object when loaded.  It allows the user to click on a point on an image.  When that point is generated, I'd like it to create a new Location object (point).  I'd like multiple different boxes on the screen to bind to the various properties of that object.  My next step will be figuring out the whole INotify thing, but I'm stuck on one part.  I can't seem to figure out how to attach the Location object to the Locations list in the Skin object.  I know there's just some logic that I'm missing which is probably super straight forward.

Here is the code-behind I'm working with:

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ManikinEditor.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ManikinEditor : Page
    {
        public List<SkinList.Skin> skin = new List<SkinList.Skin>();

        private Ellipse elip = new Ellipse();
        private Point anchorPoint;
        private int Radius = 3;
        public ManikinEditor()
        {
            string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            SkinList.Skin _skin = new SkinList.Skin();
            _skin.ID = guid;
            skin.Add(_skin);
            InitializeComponent();


        }
        private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            anchorPoint = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(Cnv);
            //public List<SkinList.Skin
            //           SkinList.Location point = new SkinList.Location();
 //           List<SkinList.List> location = new List<SkinList.Locations>();
            SkinList.Location point = new SkinList.Location();
            string pointguid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            point.ID = pointguid;
            Path test = new Path
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Fill = Brushes.Black,
                Data = new EllipseGeometry { Center = anchorPoint, RadiusX = Radius, RadiusY = Radius }
            };

            Cnv.Children.Add(test);


        }

    }
}
```

After I get everything together, I will serialize the entire thing and add it to a list (Skins) in the json file, but I'll cross that hurdle when I come to it.

Comment: What is your question? Are you able to run your code? If not, what errors do you get? If so, what happens and what do you want it to do differently?

Comment: Hi Code.  My question was about how I can make it work the way it's described.  Can't compile as I couldn't figure out what I was supposed to do to make it work.  I'm new to a number of these areas and unfortunately COVID both took away the CE course I was going to attend, and gave me nothing but time to work on this project.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of answered my own question.  It was just a case where I was treating a list object as a class object(not sure if my wording is right, I'm pretty new).  Here is the updated code that appears to work so far:

```html
    public partial class ManikinEditor : Page
    {
        public SkinList.Skin skin = new SkinList.Skin();
        List<SkinList.Location> location = new List<SkinList.Location>();
        private Ellipse elip = new Ellipse();
        private Point anchorPoint;
        private int Radius = 3;
        public ManikinEditor()
        {
            string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            skin.ID = guid;
            InitializeComponent();


        }
        private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            anchorPoint = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(Cnv);
            //public List<SkinList.Skin
            //           SkinList.Location point = new SkinList.Location();

            SkinList.Location point = new SkinList.Location();
            SkinList.Coord coord = new SkinList.Coord();
            coord.x = (int)anchorPoint.X;
            coord.y = (int)anchorPoint.Y;
            string pointguid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();       
            point.ID = pointguid;
            point.Coords = coord;
            location.Add(point);
            //           skin.Add(location);
            skin.Locations = location;
            Path test = new Path
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Fill = Brushes.Black,
                Data = new EllipseGeometry { Center = anchorPoint, RadiusX = Radius, RadiusY = Radius }
            };

            Cnv.Children.Add(test);


        }

    }
```

I guess another followup would be if this code is appropriate for code-behind following an MVVM model?  I don't know if this question is actually answerable given the limited code, but I'm trying to be good this time and do it right.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.
MVVM can be a bit daunting when first attempted, so here are some pointers.

The classes that you have created are really the data Model.

You should try and only place code that is needed to support the View within it's code behind.

Programme logic such as creating Model class instances and setting them up, should be performed within the ViewModel, which incidentally implements the INotifyPropertyChanged stuff.

Incidentally, there is often a grey area around the need for separate Model and ViewModel classes.

Your view should have Binding to ViewModel properties for data and ICommand instances for executing actions such as triggering certain code to run e.g. json serialization.

Your SkinList ViewModel should have an ObservableCollection of Skins.

Personally, I'd separate my classes out so that they're not embedded within each other, place each one in its own file.

Each class should be able to create, delete and have a selected instance of the class that it holds within a list - this will simplify Binding in the XAML.
e.g.

Don't be afraid to implement ObservableCollections of ViewModels or place ViewModels within ViewModels - ask yourself this question do you want to View a Location, Skin or Coord on it's own?

If you are looking at displaying multiple Skins and Locations within one user View, could this be best achieved by having multiple Views within the View or multiple custom user controls within the View?

For example are you looking at having a View that has multiple layers of Skins on display or just the one?

**edit**

The easiest way to pass mouse click coordinates back to the ViewModel would be to use the code behind to capture it and pass it on (you can do it through binding in the XAML it's a little more complex).

The ViewModel is the View's(Page) BindingContext (this may be set in the XAML or in the code behind). In the code behind it is typically passed in through the constructor.

You would then reference this with your 'Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1' handler and call a command passing the coordinates as command parameter.

The use of ICommands and binding helps to uncouple the UI and program code in a way that also allows them to run on different threads keeping your UI responsive.

Comment: Hi Chris.  Thanks so much for your reply.  The reason I created the class the way I did was based on this guide for json: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/from-zero-to-hero-in-json-with-c-shar/  If I'm reading you right, what you're saying is that this is my model, and I need to create a view-model to interact between this and the view?  I'll do some reading into what you talked about here.  I was all ready to take continuing ed to learn this properly, then COVID both took away that chance, and gave me a ton of time to work on this project.

Comment: To answer your other questions, this will essentially create a profile in a JSON file for each "skin".  These can then be loaded later into a different page to configure how an application will work.  Only one will be viewable at a time.  Once it's saved, the page will navigate away or a new skin will come up.  As for the locations, a new one is generated on each mouse click in the canvas area.

Comment: How would I get x and y coords from the view to the viewmodel when the mouse is clicked?